# Getting "Database open failed" exception while sending email through lotus notes with .NET

Tags: .net, lotus-notes

I am working on a task where my .net application should send emails using Lotus Notes client ( NOT SMTP) with .NET using Dominos.dll. I am able to send mails also. But the problem comes when i close my Lotus Notes mail client and try to run my application which does not deliver mails. Reason, i think they were being stored in "Outgoing mail". Again when i re-open my Lotus Notes client by entering my username and password, then the mails that were in "Outgoing mail" were been delivered.
One gentleman over her suggested me that i am connecting to my local copy to send email and told me to change my database name to the servers database file . I changed the connection to server Now i am getting this error "Database open failed." Interesting thing is if i am  using "names.nsf" file, i am not getting exception. But if i change to my "username.nsf" it could not connect and gives me this error. But if i use "names.nsf" file, mails are not getting delivered when i close lotus notes and run my app.

The following is the code that i used to send email.

```
    oNotesSession = new NotesSession();
oNotesSession.Initialize("******"); //password
oNotesDatabase = oNotesSession.GetDatabase("servername", "names.nsf", false);

if (!oNotesDatabase.IsOpen)
oNotesDatabase.Open();

oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", strToAddress);
oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("body", mData.Body);
oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", mData.Subject);
oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("$KeepPrivate", "1");
oNotesDocument.ReplaceItemValue("postDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
oItemValue = oNotesDocument.GetItemValue("SendTo");
oNotesDocument.Send(false, ref oItemValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you can open the same database using the same login you are using via .NET.  In other words, just open the Notes client and try to open that username.nsf file on the server.  Chances are you don't have rights to that server.

You definitely don't want to send emails from names.nsf, (but theoretically it will still work.)

BTW, after your call to oNotesDatabase.Open(); you need to create the Notes document:

```
oNotesDocument = oNotesDatabase.CreateDocument();
```